# Interprétation de la locution « c'est que »

Tags: sens, pronoms, conjonctions, locutions

Il existe une interprétation de cette locution qui est assez courante ; elle exprime la causalité ; elle signifie tout simplement « c'est parce que ». Elle est parfois utilisée dans ce sens en corrélation avec « si », comme ci-dessous.

- Si ce stylo n'écrit plus c'est qu'il n'y a plus d'encre dedans.

Il en existe un autre usage qui n'est pas si simple ; on le décèle dans le court dialogue suivant, que j'ai assemblé dans le but de fournir le contexte particulier où il se justifie.

> — Il n'arrête pas d'être dissipé et de ne pas faire son travail d'école ; tous ses maitres s'en plaignent.
>   — Vous pourriez essayer de le raisonner, de lui faire comprendre que sans une bonne instruction il n'aura pas un futur très heureux.
>   — *C'est qu*'il ne veut rien entendre ; j'ai bien essayé de lui parler mais tout ce que je lui dis rentre par une oreille et sort par l'autre au moment même où je lui parle, par le fait de sa volonté de m'ignorer.

Quelle serait la signification de la locution dans ce contexte ? Quel synonyme aurait-elle ? Son registre semble être assez familier mais il semble aussi qu'elle puisse être utilisée dans la langue écrite ; qu'en est-il ?
Reconnait-on des nuances de sens dans l'utilisation de cette locution ? Si oui, lesquelles ?

Comment: I've also been thinking about the opposite direction of causation. In "La vérité sur la vérité", Daniel Lavoie sings, in reference to thinking profound thoughts: "Si c'est pas payant, c'est que tu perds ton temps." Does this appear to you to be the same usage (you're wasting your time; that's why no one pays you for it)? Or the opposite: no one pays you for it; thus you're wasting your time?

Comment: @LukeSawczak In case you're thinking of similarity with the introductory example (which does not concern the question but is meant to prepare it) I must say no, your example is different: in your example there is no relation of causality, that is "Si c'est pas payant c'est *parce que* tu perd ton temps" is an erroneous interprétation; I'm fairly sure of that; on the count of this reckoning and user **survenant**'s answer (explication, rectification, objection) it follows that your example falls under a more encompassing category of enunciations, of which the one I question  (champ 1)

Comment: @LukeSawczak in my post is just a part (I failled to perceive more possibilities); yes, I think it belongs to that category, to be assimilated perhaps with Snt Exupery's "Si je vous élève, c'est que je vous tire hors de votre peau." ("explication").  (end)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm even inclined to think that a category could missing and that instead of "explication" one should speak of "adéquation": "Ce n'est pas payant" amounts to "Tu perds ton temps;"; however I'd like to have more opinions concerning that.

Comment: Indeed, that's the direction I'm leaning towards. And this "amounts to" is very close to "means that", which has the ring of causation, even if that's stretching it a bit. So whenever I read "c'est que" as a non-native speaker I have to take a second to figure out which direction the logic is pointing.

Comment: @LukeSawczak You do have to, unless you enjoy a vast reading experience and  our bane in this domain, for  most of us, whether natives or not, is that we can't afford it timewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Que](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) en emploi conjonctionnel, conjonction de subordination
>   **I.A.5.** [Introduit une complétive en fonction d'apposition]
>   [...]
>  **b)**[Apposée au pron. ce]
>  **α)** *C'est que* (littéral. «
>   ceci est, à savoir que... »). Introduit une explication de ce qui
>   précède ou bien une objection, une rectification à ce qui vient d'être
>   dit. *Sans doute on comptera les moutons d'un troupeau et l'on dira
>   qu'il y en a cinquante (...) mais c'est que l'on convient alors de
>   négliger leurs différences individuelles pour ne tenir compte que de
>   leur fonction commune* (Bergson, *Essai donn. imm.*, 1889, p.
>   68).
>  − *Si ... c'est que*. *Si je vous élève, c'est que je vous
>   tire hors de votre peau* (Saint-Exup., *Citad.*, 1944, p. 587).
>  −
>   *Est-ce que...?* (littéral. « ceci est-il, à savoir que... »). *En toute conscience, est-ce que vous croyez que Dieu me pardonnera?*
>   (Martin du G., Thib., Pénitenc., 1922, p. 736).
>  − *Ce que c'est
>   que...* (littéral. « ce que c'est, à savoir (que) »). *Ce que c'est
>   que d'avoir étudié! Ce que c'est que la vie! Mais voyez ce que c'est
>   que la vanité!* (A. Daudet, *Tartarin de T.*, 1872, p. 33).
>
> [ Trésor informatisé de la langue française (TLFi), « que » ]

[Ailleurs](http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/pages/f1153.aspx), en termes de fonction, on l'assimile à celle de subordonnée complétive complément du présentatif (*voilà, il y a, c'est*). *Le bon usage* (§1124 f) la classe comme une suite d'un introducteur (les présentatifs qui précèdent) dans le cadre d'une proposition conjonctive essentielle. À ne pas confondre avec la [mise en évidence](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5318).

---

- On introduit une *explication, une objection, une rectification*, ce qui diffère de l'idée de *causalité* présentée en question.
- *Ceci est, à savoir que*. Moins directement *à [savoir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir) que* peut être assimilé à *c'est-à-dire*.
- Ce n'est pas de registre familier.

> — Ce stylo n'a jamais fonctionné...
>  — ...c'est qu'il n'y a plus
>   d'encre dedans.

- Ça me semble introduire ici une rectification. Oui, dans le sens qu'il y a une différence entre l'explication, la
  rectification et l'objection. Je ne sais pas si la nuance découle
  d'un mot dans ce qui précède (par ex. si la réponse avait été *si ce
  stylo n'écrit plus c'est...*, serait-ce alors une rectification ou
  une rectification dans une explication ? est-ce qu'une explication qui diffère en substance d'une affirmation qui précède est une rectification etc. cette analyse ne me semble pas déterminante, ni même intéressante) ; plus probablement du contexte à mon avis.

Comment: Sur la base de la lumière projetée sur la question essentiellement par votre réponse et une constatation clé de user **cl-r**, je ne vois pas comment conclure autrement qu'en choisissant la fonction de cette locution comme étant la communication d'une objection ; je crois même que l'absence d'antécédent pourrait correspondre à cette possibilité particulière en général. Vu cet usage particulier, en admettant que vous le reconnaissiez, le registre non  familier auquel fait référence votre réponse est-il toujours applicable et quel serait la justification ? Un savoir personnel ?

Comment: @LPH Je suis pas certain de comprendre ce que veux dire _antécédent_, ça veut dire que dans la même phrase il y aurait qqc. qui précède la tournure ? Dans l'exemple _c'est qu'il ne veut rien entendre_ je vois ça comme une objection à la possibilité qu'évoque l'interlocuteur d'essayer de raisonner/faire comprendre qqch. à la personne dont on discute. Le fait qu'on soit dans deux phrases distinctes de deux interlocuteurs ne change rien à l'analyse en ce qui me concerne, LBU donne un ex. ds. la préface de [Littré](https://www.littre.org/annexes/preface) ctrl-f « basoche »...

Comment: @LPH Donc non, je ne vois pas d'usage distinct. La question du registre j'ai pas vraiment d'opinion, je ne le perçois pas comme familier, généralement je me fie à l'information provenant des sources, je n'ai pas remarqué de référence à l'idée que ce serait familier, Littré ne s'exprime pas dans un registre familier, ni Camus au LBU : « On peut trouver à Oran [...] une édifiante abondance de magasins funéraires. Ce n'est pas qu'à Oran on meure plus qu'ailleurs ». C'est ce qui serait différent de la norme qui doit être justifié, pas ce qui s'y conforme. Remarque mon opinion en vaut une autre.

Comment: Peut-être que dans ton dialogue, [_mais_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais/1) aurait été un bon substitut à _c'est que_, parce qu'il marque l'opposition... Est-ce que dire ça, qu'on transpose différemment, fait en sorte que c'est un usage distinct de _c'est que_, je sais pas trop. Je trouve plus simple de dire qu'on introduit quelque chose, et que ce qui est introduit varie (explication, une objection, une rectification), que de dire qu'il s'agit d'usage distinct...

Answer (score 2):

Le problème  est, la situation est, qu'il  ne veut plus rien entendre.

Le même  raisonnement s'applique pour le stylo et l'encre. Il s'agit  d'une constatation, *il n'y a plus d'encre*,  qui éventuellement  explique.

Comment: Pour le stylo et l'encre on peut faire le remplacement par « c'est parce que », mais si on fait cela pour la phrase au sens à déterminer la causalité ne correspond à rien.

Comment: Je pense qu'ici il ne faut pas trop se focaliser sur un remplacement immédiat par *parce que*. *C'est que* introduit une explication, une précision. C'est le point essentiel. On peut aussi remplacer la phrase par *j'ai un problème avec lui parce qu'il ne veut rien entendre*, même si c'est alors beaucoup plus lourd.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la phrase précédant le locuteur emploie des verbes d’action, d’avoir, de possession qui veulent imposer le point de vue du locuteur pour avoir raison contre l’attitude d’un enfant.

Une réponse sur le même registre entraînerait une conversation vaine ; *c’**est** que* est alors le *témoignage d’un état*, seule façon d’échapper à un sermon sur la bonne éducation, en même temps qu’il indique les limites de la verbalisation.
 Tout enseignant sait que ce n’est pas ce qu’il dit qui compte pour l’enfant, mais lui-même, qui il est… et la suite de la conversation montre que la façon d’être de l’adulte ne convient pas à l’enfant, il a perdu sa confiance et son écoute, il est alors accusé de n’en faire qu’à sa tête (on repart dans les verbes d’action)…

> ***[C’est que](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22c%27est%20que%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1976,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=YkXTXIHSOpC-a_nkiIgO&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiBi4Xs64ziAhUQ3xoKHXkyAuEQ8tMDCF0&biw=1111&bih=479&dpr=1.5)*** est l’argument témoin d’une situation incontournable, d’une réalité qui ne peut être remise immédiatement en cause, et donc, le langage soutenu ou familier lui convient.

Comment: Je ne suis pas  d'accord avec l'interprétation  des éléments du dialogue ; en de nombreux points on y trouve un trop grand degré d'extrapolation, qui de plus ne semble pas utile à la détermination du sens de « C'est que ». Je retiens «argument témoin d'une situation incontournable » cependant sans comprendre les référence fournies comme dans tous les cas il s'agit d'un contexte dans lequel se trouve un antécédent; il y a une grand différence en ce qui concerne ce dialogue : il n'existe apparemment pas d'antécédent.

Comment: @LPH — Pour faire simple, disons je n’aborde pas le français par la grammaire, ses règles et contraintes que les yeux lisent et apprennent, mais par la philologie, l’observation attentive et l’écoute pour apprivoiser les mots, les remettre dans la musique et la sensibilité de l’oralité. Le dialogue pourrait seul poursuivre cet échange, mais que vous acceptiez le sens de *c’est que* me suffit, merci de votre commentaire.